# Error in the POST method of Writable Nested serializers in django with form data

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

**models.py**

```
class Client(models.Model):

    client_id = models.CharField(max_length=50,default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    org = models.ForeignKey(Organisation, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='org',null=True)
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product,related_name='product')
    client_name = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=100)
    client_code = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=20)
    client_logo = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_to, null=True, blank=True,)
    currency = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    currency_type = models.CharField(max_length=100,choices=CURRENCY_CHOICES,default='Indian Rupee')
    billing_method = models.ForeignKey(Billing_Method, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='client_billingmethod', null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email_id = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    contact_no = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Billing_Method(models.Model):
    billing_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    billing_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=250)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class Billingmethod_Serializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Billing_Method
        fields = ('billing_id', 'billing_name', 'description')

class Clientpost_Serializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    billing_method = Billingmethod_Serializers()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        billing_method_data = validated_data.pop('billing_method')
        billing_method = Billing_Method.objects.create(**billing_method_data)
        client = Client.objects.create(billing_method=billing_method,**validated_data)
        return client

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ('client_id','currency','currency_type','billing_method','first_name','last_name',...)
```

**view.py**

```
class Clientlist(APIView):
    renderer_classes = (CustomRenderer,)
    parser_classes = [parsers.MultiPartParser, parsers.FormParser]
   
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        clients = models.Client.objects.all()
        serializer = serializers.Client_Serializers(clients, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = serializers.Clientpost_Serializers(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

When i was trying to do POST in client I was getting an errro as
"
TypeError at /api/onboarding/client/
django.db.models.manager.BaseManager._get_queryset_methods..create_method..manager_method() argument after ** must be a mapping, not list
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/onboarding/client/
Django Version: 3.2.12
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:
django.db.models.manager.BaseManager._get_queryset_methods..create_method..manager_method() argument after ** must be a mapping, not list
Exception Location: F:\PM-Onboarding-Service\Onboarding-Service\microservices\onboarding\serializers.py, line 34, in create
"

I was doing a Post method in form data as below,
[image]

Please help me to solve this error, and let me know how to post the billing method in the form data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you uploaded `billing_method` as a list in POST API.
But in serializer, you defined it as not a list, but a dictionary.
So you should upload `billing _method` as an object in postman like the
following.

```
{
    ...
    "client_code": "...",
    "product": "...",        
    "billing_method": {
        "billing_name": "...",
        "description": "...",
        ...
    }
}
```